# Is there a way to rotate APNs Auth token + Key ID without downtime?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm using a Token-Based connection to APNs and I would like to rotate the Key ID + Auth token. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns

Is there a way to do it without causing downtime in my push notification service?

As far as I know, you can only have one Key ID and Auth Token at a time.

Comment: You can have two keys at once to allow for exactly this scenario. You can't issue a third key until one of the first two are revoked

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, you're absolutely right. This is embarrassing... I just realised we already had two keys and the developer portal wouldn't let me create a new one. We must have created the second one for testing or something, and I didn't realise until now. Thanks!